# How to undo _changes_ to a specific file in an old commit in Git?

Tags: git, tortoisegit

This might be a duplicate, I just didn't happen to find one.

Basically the scenario is: there were some minor changes to a file  in some commit, and now the file has been modified even more (to add new features, etc.).

What I would like to do is to automatically undo (if possible) the *changes* to the file in that commit, *without* actually going back to an old revision of the file; i.e., whatever the diff for that commit was, the reverse of it should be applied to the current version.  The result is a new "fixed" version of the latest file.

I realize it isn't always possible for a computer to do this, but when the future changes after the bad commit are completely unrelated and in a different location, it should be possible. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

find out the commitish you want to undo and `revert` it:

```
$ git revert 53ab103e8f
```

will revert commit `53ab103e8f` (by creating a new entry in your repository, that explicitely reverts that change; if there are problems with reverting, you will be asked to manually resolve the conflict)

Comment: +1 D'oh, I didn't know that's what revert does, haha. I thought it goes back to that commit. Thanks!